# Deploying a function from the Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have created a Pub Sub Function in the `Console` and I want to upload a folder with my project **using the console** and not using terminal, every time I have an update.
I use Python.

In the Docs they say I can find a button to upload ZIP, but there is nothing like this.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console

Question is :

1. How do I upload my project from Console ? I can see the default source code in console.
2. Do I need to call my entry file `main.py` or `index.py` ?
3. Do I need to set up `requirement.txt` file by myself? I can't see it in my project in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to click '`edit`' button to edit the Function, then in the 'Source' tab, left to the source, there is a drop down, where you can see "Upload Zip".

Doing this in the Terminal seems to be easier :

```
sudo gcloud functions deploy Project_name
```